# $(X,Z) \overset{d}{\sim} (Y,Z) \implies \mathbb E [ f(X) | Z ] = \mathbb E [ f(Y) | Z ] $

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am trying to prove that statement :

$$(X,Z) \overset{d}{\sim} (Y,Z) \implies \mathbb E [ f(X) | Z ] = \mathbb E [ f(Y) | Z ].$$

First I know that $ (X,Z) \overset{d}{\sim} (Y,Z) \implies (X) \overset{d}{\sim} (Y) $. Thus I indeed have

$$\mathbb E f(X) = \mathbb E f(Y) $$

but I don't think this would be true when one changes the measure of the expectation. I don't know how to use the hypothesis that the joint distributions are equal (thus using the conditions on $Z$).

Comment: First note that if as stated than $(f(X), Z)$ and $(f(X), Z)$ have same distribution. And then just use the fact that for any fixed value of $Z$, $f(X)|Z$ and $f(Y)|Z$ have same distribution. It is indeed enough.

Comment: @kolobokish thanks for the comment. The second part of your message is not yet really clear in my mind. Would it be possible to elaborate a little on that?

Comment: Of course. equality in multivariate distribution means $P(X \in A, Z\in B)=P(Y \in A, Z\in B)$, for any $A, B$ in appropriate sigma-algebra. So when you fix any value of $Z=z$ () or even a set. You'll have $P(X \in A, Z = z)=P(Y \in A, Z = z)$. When defining marginal $|Z$ you just divide the previous by $P(Z=z)$. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ is a random variable $V$ such that $\mathbb E\left[V\mathbf{1}_A\right]=0$ 
for each $A$ in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, then $\mathbb E\left[V\mid \mathcal A\right]=0$. Apply this to $\mathcal A=\sigma(Z)$ and $V=f(X)-f(Y)$: a set in $\mathcal A$ has the form $Z^{-1}(B)$ for a Borel set $B$ and 
$$
\mathbb E\left[f(X)\mathbf 1_{Z^{-1}(B)}\right]= 
\mathbb E\left[f(X)\mathbf 1_{Z\in B}\right]= \mathbb E\left[f(Y)\mathbf 1_{Z\in B}\right].
$$

Comment: quick point, is the r v $V$ important here ? wy did you mentionned when the second line is proving the equality since $ \mathbb E[ f(X) | Z ] =  \mathbb  E[ f(x) 1_Z ] /   \mathbb  P( Z) $

Comment: In general, $\mathbb E[ f(X) | Z ] =  \mathbb  E[ f(X) 1_Z ] /   \mathbb  P( Z)$ does not hold since the left hand side is a random variable and the right hand side a fixed real number; maybe you confused with $\mathbb E[ f(X) ;Z ]$. The role of $V$ was just to write the general statement in the first line.